# How to solve application error in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

Hello and good day to you Programmer.

I have a problem. My **Heroku** goes **"application error"** after a few minutes. I thought **setInterval function** would solve the problem, but it turns out it doesn't. I have to **"heroku restart"** it to work.

**MySQL connection is working fine.**
[image]

So I try to find the bug in **"heroku error --tails"** and this is what I found.

**When I ran the code, this shows up.**
[image]

**After a few minutes, it goes Application Error.**

[image]

**This is the error output after it goes Application.**
[image]

**Heroku error --tails**

```
PS C:\Users\Drinesby\Documents\last\3ISC-GROUP3> heroku logs --tail
2020-12-11T01:51:17.724853+00:00 app[web.1]: at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
2020-12-11T01:51:17.724854+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
2020-12-11T01:51:17.724854+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL'
2020-12-11T01:51:17.724854+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-12-11T01:51:17.736976+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-12-11T01:51:17.737189+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-12-11T01:51:17.742075+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! WebProject@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2020-12-11T01:51:17.742194+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-12-11T01:51:17.742304+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-12-11T01:51:17.742388+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the WebProject@1.0.0 start script.
2020-12-11T01:51:17.742460+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-12-11T01:51:17.752537+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-11T01:51:17.752539+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-12-11T01:51:17.752540+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-12-11T01_51_17_743Z-debug.log
2020-12-11T01:51:17.817313+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-12-11T01:51:17.843878+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-12-11T02:12:20.974108+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=ba604873-bc5d-4b5f-8f04-c78392f352e0 fwd="110.54.195.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:12:24.541348+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=8adc8f8b-4e9c-4d5c-8e37-9a3462f77bff fwd="110.54.195.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:02.995364+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=004b6be0-4983-4ccb-8175-916478eafaec fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:03.572856+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=becf05ca-d21b-4415-b08d-cb3b95448b57 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:39.416017+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-11T02:25:42.543048+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-12-11T02:25:45.810461+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-11T02:25:45.810498+00:00 app[web.1]: > WebProject@1.0.0 start /app
2020-12-11T02:25:45.810499+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2020-12-11T02:25:45.810500+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-11T02:25:46.326357+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on port 33199
2020-12-11T02:25:46.357093+00:00 app[web.1]: MYSQL Connected!
2020-12-11T02:25:46.727708+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-12-11T02:25:47.230320+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=3085f2e9-4d7a-4e7c-af1c-8d9153353d95 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=46ms status=200 bytes=6027 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:47.503973+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/bootstrap.min.css" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=fc9d18a7-36ca-488d-b037-3e7e956947f3 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:47.510490+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/style.css" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=641f3cff-42f5-4635-b0e3-a9f27d60e89b fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:47.744722+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=6194a603-b268-4d16-b844-15d1186c1f8c fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:47.790341+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=e3124f9f-b046-4b46-bdd4-68bc1b4b827c fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:47.969897+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/popper.min.js" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=4bb0c989-47ce-4dc4-995a-054106766d9a fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:47.980008+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/all.min.js" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=16fb15a3-de91-4ad8-9f36-3153013436ba fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=240 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:47.990429+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/logo%20circle%20(1).png" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=86b827b5-0ca8-439c-88a8-84a5f231ed6a fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:48.004963+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/2.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=ced65e0d-80ef-4863-9455-5b7ef8d6d582 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:48.047391+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.2.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=2c141e30-ad41-494a-85ea-b43cb8ccd590 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:48.056364+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.1.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=38b9b70c-eea6-47b4-82e8-fac85b1fe9a5 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:48.207581+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/1.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=d4e892d9-fe57-4d53-9b98-00b1f9390641 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:48.218752+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=9ed74fbf-1ae3-4ebf-a016-9b56617e73fb fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:48.235114+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.3.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=1ddf5494-6a11-4fab-8b90-884135f47ba0 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:48.396256+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/3.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=6a4a9053-d466-484b-abe9-9c69e077a280 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:48.404353+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.4.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=da296832-af4d-4967-9aa9-df34608de04e fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:25:48.487618+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/5.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=02496ec4-7221-467d-a91d-242726548ee9 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:56.465527+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=fa6acc89-08c2-49e3-b1e6-b8833804adfc fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=152 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:56.752197+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/style.css" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=285b45ba-48bd-487c-9887-9e7c5d14160f fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=18ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:56.753797+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/bootstrap.min.css" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=c93e49ad-e015-4cc1-8f37-d37a0fc24fa2 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=26ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:56.757484+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=47d4964a-f586-4ea2-8515-c165c2c6af29 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=15ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:56.989240+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=8392a92d-a6ae-45f1-b07d-c4b35ba9a4f7 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:56.994550+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/popper.min.js" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=d0b340ab-2740-40ea-b671-57de4c91e83b fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:57.004077+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/all.min.js" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=4c329fcd-b2e5-4aa5-bcd6-294d85deedc2 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=240 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:57.201841+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.3.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=f01c4cef-71e7-4221-a222-bb8c27839ffe fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:57.202480+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=41f95583-f721-45e5-bb45-a4ca4ce9586f fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:57.209742+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.2.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=f9b838cc-b422-4ff3-8287-f8004571625e fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:57.223427+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.1.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=bce0c231-ec7c-4a80-85c8-f72f9b68445f fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:57.229322+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/logo%20circle%20(1).png" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=087b134d-3c01-4f1d-9295-eb924d05c3d9 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:57.243203+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/2.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=0073ce3a-8f61-4eba-bc49-fd11b7b0d992 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:57.441079+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/1.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=e014c241-1748-474f-a0f2-0267d9fb28b6 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:57.444427+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/3.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=b733dcf5-5efd-4a38-87bf-ceeae09071ad fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:57.458589+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.4.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=ebd11ea8-4a5b-4c79-86b8-6e70b0ba937e fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:57.464198+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/5.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=2abad1b0-8b82-4d4d-b9c5-1abdfd24340d fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:26:57.712022+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/logo.ico" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=13a6ed5c-78a1-4a23-b955-0af773107661 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=71817 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:01.982525+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=9f99b512-3b69-4e0b-969f-b0a0ab28823e fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=304 bytes=152 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:02.243107+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/bootstrap.min.css" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=7392ba7b-45c0-4145-ab3f-83cd16689511 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:02.258775+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=c25ce91a-70f8-4e75-9721-613b6a5234df fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:02.477163+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=466774de-78ad-4fb2-95b1-c1e855532fa5 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:02.509259+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/popper.min.js" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=124a35be-74fb-4c1e-9dcb-6440daa4e77f fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:02.714026+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/all.min.js" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=1151a72c-5548-4c0c-9251-ae3b081b5e81 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=240 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:02.723902+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/logo%20circle%20(1).png" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=3343f83c-b618-4df8-a705-b89c8780197c fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:02.729465+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/2.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=399ff098-aac1-4388-bbc6-6fa076ef99c2 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:02.742148+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/1.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=6286c32f-11bc-4f6c-99cb-a0fe3034306d fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:02.748816+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.1.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=6066c5ef-4742-4e27-a519-0c6a82205d0a fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:02.951587+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.2.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=e3784f44-fe7a-4a18-80e8-54d94e5c8459 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:02.960215+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.3.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=57152b97-1209-44d1-ab8a-3bf85168a17e fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:02.972890+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=fa755c89-d9a5-4fa4-ac5e-7c8c7fc92a8b fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:02.985885+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.4.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=e42666b5-198c-4b97-8e0f-a2d817b38a67 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:02.987536+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/3.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=293a5229-1b43-4c36-9a9a-ff823e16968d fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=8ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:03.042286+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/style.css" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=805d8193-81e8-488b-baeb-5bd2573ad5e2 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:03.188620+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/5.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=3cd160bc-1bcf-4887-8ac5-6877ba396d9c fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:03.450227+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/logo.ico" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=9340a9ee-f3ed-4145-a5be-9023fac24585 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=200 bytes=71817 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:47.392797+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=5db5a8a1-d6d1-4ede-990b-43eb2ad86f28 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=152 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:47.652485+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/bootstrap.min.css" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=2da93b29-761d-4593-82ea-4d4240d7668d fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:47.656469+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/style.css" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=f33f2850-06ee-4032-9d85-148431f47eaa fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:47.674707+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=d2a6c037-6dc1-47d9-bef6-7f4fb420b05e fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:47.679326+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=f81448b5-f2d5-4f87-b080-7407072b0bda fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:47.690491+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/popper.min.js" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=dc27b74f-33d2-4d0b-96f2-9ee7f87a6dec fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:47.697845+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/all.min.js" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=dd104b6b-2e3d-480c-8d77-1c4c890ca2a5 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=240 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:47.889481+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/logo%20circle%20(1).png" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=dc2c5225-894b-4948-998d-8599f674dc78 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:47.895741+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/2.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=5edf7509-708a-4ddf-b32f-1030f082fa6b fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:47.916921+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/1.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=818bdc76-97f7-4b1c-959b-bdca9dc85144 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:47.918815+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.3.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=9dfb754a-5b37-4327-b416-b581da7ffd11 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:47.925912+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=a2bc4e2a-b1c3-4013-b58e-c8c297883963 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:47.936416+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.2.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=9a5a7780-2eb8-4122-8657-323c0edd2297 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:48.124155+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.1.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=56274f1a-b585-4b3d-8a83-bc61b819caa9 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:48.130964+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/3.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=d4c9bb88-a928-410c-9ec3-f47dc69b4b0a fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:48.157139+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/4.4.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=9773c7b5-2a6d-431e-97e0-61be8cb62604 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:48.166753+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/5.jpg" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=66415099-9053-484f-beba-fa6ceb7249b1 fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:28:48.436484+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/logo.ico" host=fierce-wildwood-50918.herokuapp.com request_id=25cbf444-ca81-4fb3-bd13-3543d1716aab fwd="112.200.235.49" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=71817 protocol=https
2020-12-11T02:30:46.329559+00:00 app[web.1]: _http_client.js:151
2020-12-11T02:30:46.329573+00:00 app[web.1]: throw new ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL(protocol, expectedProtocol);
2020-12-11T02:30:46.329574+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-12-11T02:30:46.329575+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-11T02:30:46.329576+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:"
2020-12-11T02:30:46.329576+00:00 app[web.1]: at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:151:11)
2020-12-11T02:30:46.329577+00:00 app[web.1]: at request (http.js:46:10)
2020-12-11T02:30:46.329578+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.get (http.js:50:15)
2020-12-11T02:30:46.329578+00:00 app[web.1]: at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/app.js:32:10)
2020-12-11T02:30:46.329579+00:00 app[web.1]: at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
2020-12-11T02:30:46.329579+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
2020-12-11T02:30:46.329580+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL'
2020-12-11T02:30:46.329580+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-12-11T02:30:46.349522+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-12-11T02:30:46.350223+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-12-11T02:30:46.359423+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! WebProject@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2020-12-11T02:30:46.359758+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-12-11T02:30:46.360015+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-12-11T02:30:46.360325+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the WebProject@1.0.0 start script.
2020-12-11T02:30:46.360540+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-12-11T02:30:46.370983+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-11T02:30:46.371288+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-12-11T02:30:46.371479+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-12-11T02_30_46_361Z-debug.log
2020-12-11T02:30:46.465885+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-12-11T02:30:46.751130+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed      
2020-12-11T02:30:46.755492+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-11T02:30:50.333105+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-12-11T02:30:53.323685+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-11T02:30:53.323710+00:00 app[web.1]: > WebProject@1.0.0 start /app
2020-12-11T02:30:53.323711+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2020-12-11T02:30:53.323711+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-11T02:30:53.784760+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on port 27047
2020-12-11T02:30:53.823334+00:00 app[web.1]: MYSQL Connected!
2020-12-11T02:30:54.142033+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

**My app.js content is this:**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
//const session = require('express-session');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user'); //for 'define router'
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({path: './.env'});

//http heroku
const http = require('http');

//view engines of ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('layout', './layouts/layout');
app.use(cookieParser());
//app.use(session({secret: 'mysupersecret'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join('public')));

//define router
app.use('/', userRoutes);
//app.use(require('./routes/user'));

//port
const port  = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

**Here's my package.json**

```
{
  "name": "WebProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "I removed it. Ignore this."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "I removed it. Ignore this."
  },
  "homepage": "I removed it. Ignore this.",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-ejs-layouts": "^2.5.0",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.15",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

**My database.js**

```
const mysql2 = require('mysql2');

//database connection
const con = mysql2.createConnection({
  host: 'I removed it. Ignore this.',
  user: 'I removed it. Ignore this.',
  password: 'I removed it. Ignore this.',
  database: 'I removed it. Ignore this.',
  port: 3306
});

//to run heroku indefinitely
setInterval(()=> {
    con.query('SELECT 1 FROM products');
},5000);

con.connect((error) => {
    if(error) {
        console.log("MYSQL NOT Connected!");
    }
    else {
        console.log("MYSQL Connected!");
    }
});

module.exports = con;
```

I have a procfile too.

```
web:node app.js
```

Comment: is you app trying to connect to a external http resource?

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I don't understand that part. All I know is that my web has "https://" and it connects smoothly. Then crashes a few minutes later.

Comment: I think the error is when a http call is performed from inside of your nodejs app to an external resource. Also this part `const http = require('http');` supports my theory.  Is your snippet complete?

Comment: It worked when I removed the http package. Thank you! It's up and running till this day.